# if(string.Contains(string)). Is that possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to check if a string is contained in another string.  Code behind is pretty straight forward.  How can I do that in jquery?

```
function deleteRow(locName, locID) {
    if(locName.Contains(locID)) {
        alert("success");
    }
}
```

Comment: @Fredrik Mörk: fixed, it probably has to do with the codebehind he's referring to since it's the only .NET term I see.

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript : string contains ...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/javascript-string-contains)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`String.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

For example: `(locName.indexOf(locID) > -1)`

String.prototype.contains doesn't exist.

Comment: +1 for doc link, I get lazy with that sometimes although I do it **a lot** with jQuery-specific methods...

Comment: @BoltClock but jQuery specific methods have nothing to do with strings. jQuery is for ajax, event handling and dom manipulation.

Comment: @Raynos: I know, I'm talking about when I answer jQuery questions.

Comment: @BoltClock That's because you can just write "api.jquery.com" + methodName. I actaully have to google the url for mdc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) method of the string. If you really want the convenience of having a `contains` method, you could add one to `String.prototype`:

```
String.prototype.contains = function(str) {
    return this.indexOf(str) > -1;
};

alert("foobar".contains("oob")); // true
alert("foobar".contains("baz")); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use indexOf if the string is found returned result will be different from -1

```
function deleteRow(locName, locID) {
    if(locName.indexOf(locID) != -1) {
        alert("success");
    }
}
```

I hope this helps